# How to have different properties file for different machines?

Tags: java, properties, apache-commons

So I am working in a team of people on a small school project, and we're developing java/jsp web app with apache.. I created simple properties.config file so I can store values and use them later and it looks something like this:

```
home_url = http://localhost:8080/to3/
to3_path = C:/Users/User2/Documents/workspace/TO-3
db_url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/to3?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Problem I have is when I commit it and someone do a checkout they have to change values for url-s and paths so it fits their machine.. I heard I can make a custom properties file which will override these default values if it recognizes certain machine, but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't commit project settings. Put them in `.gitignore` and commit a copy of it (e.g. `properties.config.sample`). Make sure to keep it up to date with any new keys you add, but each developer should make their own *untracked* copy.

Answer (score 0):

As Amadan point out you should not commit project properties. My suggestion is to create a file with .properties extension and place your properties inside. To use this file in java you can create a class like that

```
public class MyProperties{
    private String homeUrl = "";
    private String to3Path = "";
    private String dbPath = "";

    private final String configPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "my-props.properties";

    public void loadProperties(){
        try {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            InputStream input = null;
            File filePath = new File(configPath);
            input = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);
            homeUrl = prop.getProperty("home_url");
            to3Path = prop.getPropert("to3_path");
            dbPath = prop.getProperty("db_url");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // getters & setters 
}
```

Then in your app you can do

```
MyProperties props = new MyProperties();
props.loadProperties();
String homeUrl = props.getHomeUrl();
```

`System.getProperty("user.home")` will give home path depending on the OS. 
For example in windows this is path is `C:\Users\yourName`

This way all your co-workers can place their own properties in their personal pc inside their home path and you will be able to work without conflicts.